# Python regex only check a substring if it follwed by a substring

Tags: python, regex

I want to match all the numbers in a string given in scientific notation, heres my program

```
import re
txt = '2310163 -204.1154263 -204.1159668 -204.1110188 -204E-9668 200-100'
print re.findall('([+-]?\d+\.?[eE]?[+-]?\d*)', txt)
#                              ^    ^
#                             ex   sg
# allow sg only if its followed by ex
```

Now the `200-100` is not a valid number but the regex matches it, because I have given a `[+-]` for the exponent part. Now how to make regex so that it only checks for `[+-]` if it just followed by `[eE]` like the number `-204E-9668` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the whole scientific notation part into an optional group, while matching the possible decimal part separately, before:

```
[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:[eE][+-]\d+)?
#        ^^^^^^^^^ optional decimals
#                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ optional scientific notation
```

If you want *none* of the `200-100` part to match because the `200` is *right next* to the 100, then at the beginning, lookbehind for a space or the beginning of the string, and at the end, lookahead for a space or the end of the string:

```
(?:(?<=^)|(?<= ))[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:[eE][+-]\d+)?(?= |$)
```

https://regex101.com/r/SdA295/1

Comment: the end should be `(?= |$|\n)` for working with python multiline string ?

Comment: Sure, or with `\r\n` as well, depending on where the input comes from

Comment: also the start should be `(?<=^)|(?<=\s)` there can be a tab before the number, i guess?

Comment: Sure, if that's what your input is like, you can also lookahead for just `$` or `\s`

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is a positive lookahead

```
(?=foo)
```

Here's a good resource on the topic: https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html

Comment: What question are you answering?